# Extract part of filename with Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a certain part of files using Python. The file names vary so I cannot specify where to start using a specific string.

The filenames look like this:

`ABC1D2E34_**ABC12345-67-Q89**_ABC12345_6_7_Scoring.csv`

The bolded part is what I want to grab. The beginning of the files are all different and the rest of the file varies depending on where the file is stored so I need a way to grab the string without being too specific.

```
name = re.findall('_(\S*[-]\S*[-])_', list)
```

I have tried using the code above and can get **ABC12345-67-**. 
However, when I try to add on to get the last bit, I keep getting more than I need: **ABC12345-67-Q89_ABC12345_6_7_**

It seems like there should be a simple fix but I have not figured it out yet so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://regex101.com/ it's great for regex building! (be sure to set it to python at the left)

Comment: if it's guaranteed to be the second between `_`s then normal string split it and use that (eg: `s.split('_', 2)[1]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple using two negated character sets, the first being anchored at the start of the string:

```
filename = 'ABC1D2E34_ABC12345-67-Q89_ABC12345_6_7_Scoring.csv'
print(re.findall('^[^_]+_([^_]+)',filename))
```

Prints:

```
['ABC12345-67-Q89']
```

Please note that regex is not the only, and indeed **not the best solution** to achieve this.

You may use `filename.split('_')[1]` as mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: Um... if it pattern matches more than once  (or not at all )- what then?

Comment: Looks like a sophisticated version of `filename.split('_')[1]` to me.

Comment: The substring OP is trying to extract is the second occurrence, so not sure I get your comment Jon. @bereal It is. I wanted to show OP how to use `regex` since that's what his attempt shows.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness sure... I'm just not convinced a regex is *needed* is all.

Comment: @JonClements Indeed. I have added a comment in my answer to account for that.